# Intercept HTTP Header in Angular

Tags: angular, http, csrf

**Setup:**

I have a legacy REST application that I do not have source code for.  I also also have an accompanying JSP application that I do not have source code for.   The jSP application calls the back-end REST application.

I am in the process of building an Angular application to replace the JSP front-end.  I've placed the JSP application and Angular application the SAME tomcat so to avoid any CORS issues, the JSP application embeds the Angular app in an iFrame so the Cookies are set correctly.

**Issue:**

When I make a POST call to the back-end REST application I get a 403 error.  After debugging I believe it come down to two lines in the header:

Works:

```
..other headers..
x-csrf-token: <CSRF-TOKEN>
Cookie: JSESSIONID=<SESSIONID>; x-csrf-token=<CSRF-TOKEN>
..other headers..
```

Doesn't Work:

```
..other headers..
Cookie: JSESSIONID=<SESSIONID>; x-csrf-token=<CSRF-TOKEN>
..other headers..
```

So it seems the legacy REST application is validating the x-csrf-token key.

**Question:**

How do I intercept the Cookie in the HTTP Request so I can pull out the x-csrf-token to set that as a separate item?  I've tried the HttpInterceptor, but that catches it before the Cookie is set.  Also tried adding 'withCredentials: true', that doesn't work either.

**Note:** My Angular application is getting the proper Cookie set, that part works.  However missing the csrf-token.

Answer (score 2):

Angular HttpClient already has an option to set CSRF token, see [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection). You can configure the cookie name and header name and HttpClient will set the token for all POST request.

```
imports: [
  HttpClientModule,
  HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
    cookieName: 'My-Xsrf-Cookie',
    headerName: 'My-Xsrf-Header',
  }),
],
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for.  I added to app.module.ts this code to the imports: 

HttpClientXsrfModule.withOptions({
      cookieName: 'x-csrf-token',
      headerName: 'x-csrf-token',
    })
 
I get 

SET-COOKIE x-csrf-token=<token>
SET=COOKIE JESSIONID=<SESSIONID>

Is this just a quirky/bad implementation from the backend server or I missing something?

Comment: that's the way to implement it

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer would normally work.  I think the issue I'm having is my Angular app isn't actually logging in, and is not the first  page loaded.  The JSP app does the authentication and gets those cookies back.  The embedded Angular app seems to be getting the COOKIE set as part of the header (no code from me), but it's not getting the x-csrf-token set.  I have a feeling that what I am trying to do is what csrf is designed to prevent, one app piggy backing on another app's session - even from the same app server.  Sounds right?